# How to define dynamic configuration using the TreeBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I want to configure a bundle to allow different behavior for different companies. The config structure within them will be the same.

My `config.yml` shall look like this:

```
bunde_namespace:
    company:
        company_1:
            foo: bar
            baz: poit
        company_2:
            foo: bar
            baz: poit
        company_3:
            ...
```

When I access the `$config` I expect the array to look something like this:

```
$config['company'] = [
    'company_one' => [
        'foo' => 'bar'
        'baz' => 'poit'
    ],
    'company_two' => [
        'foo' => 'bar'
        'baz' => 'poit'
    ],
    ...
];
```

Yet I have no experience with the TreeBuilder and [setting up the configuration as described in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html) and it still eludes me as to how I setup my configuration so that it treats the children of `company` as keyed arrays.

What I achieved so far is to setup the config for one company, like so:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('dreamlines_booking_service_fibos');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->arrayNode('company')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('foo')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('baz')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
        ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And the simplified `config.yml` would look like this:

```
bundle_namespace:
    company:
        foo: bar
        baz: poit
```

Yet this is not what I want.

I am assuming that I need to use `useAttributeAsKey` yet I have trouble getting it work.

This fails:

```
    $rootNode
        ->children()
        ->arrayNode('company')
            ->prototype('array')
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('foo')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('baz')->end()
                ->end()
           ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

stating:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinitionException]
>   ->useAttributeAsKey() is not applicable to concrete nodes at path "bundle_namespace."

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is caused when you try to apply `useAttributeAsKey` on a prototype, but since the method is a part of the [ArrayNodeDefinition](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ArrayNodeDefinition.html#method_useAttributeAsKey), it needs to be added right after `->arrayNode(...)`. Try it this way, and the error will disappear.

Now, if I understood your question correctly, the following output is the one you aim for:

```
Array
(
    [company] => Array
        (
            [company_1] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                    [baz] => baz
                )

            [company_2] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                    [baz] => baz
                )

        )

)
```

which you can achieve with the following structure:

```
$rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('company')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('foo')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('baz')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

the configuration loaded:

```
app:
    company:
        company_1:
            foo: bar
            baz: baz
        company_2:
            foo: bar
            baz: baz
```

Please, include a comment if I misunderstood your question.