# Symfony Config Treebuilder

Tags: symfony

I'm looking to create a configuration like the following:

```
root_node:
    static_key:
        dynamic_key_1: [array, of, values]
        dynamic_key_2: [array, of, values]
```

I can't seem to figure out the correct Treebuilder syntax.

I've tried:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('static_key')
            ->prototype('scalar')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

but I get:

> Invalid type for path "root_node.static_key.dynamic_key_1". Expected scalar, but got array.

and when I switch to:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('static_key')
            ->prototype('array')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

I get:

> Unrecognized options "0, 1, 2" under "root_node.static_key.dynamic_key_1"

I've eventually figured out I could have the configuration pass using:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('static_key')
            ->prototype('variable')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

but that doesn't guarantee I get an array.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

---

I know I can do something like this:

```
/// treebuilder
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('static_key')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('attr_1')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('attr_2')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;

# config.yml
root_node:
    static_key:
        # two different syntaxes for emphasis
        dynamic_key_1:
            attr_1: value_1
            attr_2: value_2
        dynamic_key_2: {attr_1: value_3, attr_2: value_4}
```

and receive the following PHP array:

```
array('root_node' => array(
    'static_key' => array(
        'dynamic_key_1' => array(
            'attr_1' => 'value_1', 
            'attr_2' => 'value_2'
        ),
        'dynamic_key_2' => array(
            'attr_1' => 'value_3', 
            'attr_2' => 'value_4'
        ),
    ),
));
```

I've done it before.

I just done know why I can't strictly ask for a non-associative array:

What's so different about `{attr_1: value_3, attr_2: value_4}` vs `[value_3, value_4]`? To me, both are arrays: one is associative, and the other is not.

Comment: Have you tried this "In order to maintain the array keys use the useAttributeAsKey() method:" from this section http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-nodes ?

Comment: Is the dynamic key unique? If so, it seems related to what I was trying as pointed out in this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288144/how-to-define-dynamic-configuration-using-the-treebuilder

Comment: @k0pernikus I have done something like that. I find it odd that you can setup Treebuilder to strictly accept `dynamic_key_1: {key_1: value_1, key_2: value_2, key_3: value_3}` but seemingly not `dynamic_key_1: [value_1, value_2, value_3]`

Comment: @anegrea I don't have issues with maintaining the keys. They come through fine in other configurations I've set up. I just don't see why I'm allowed to have one configuration, but not the other (see above comment).

Comment: I guess the difference comes from yaml: symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections "YAML is a simple language ... but unlike PHP, it makes a difference between arrays (sequences) and hashes (mappings)."

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic keys are not supported.

you should make something like this:

```
root_node:
    static_key:
        - { key: dynamic_key_1, value: [array, of, values] }
        - { key: dynamic_key_2, value: [array, of, values] }
```

and if i am right you might get something like this:

```
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('static_key')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('key')->isRequired()->end()
                        ->arrayNode('value')
                            ->prototype('scalar')
                            ->end()
                       ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
```

Comment: Dynamic keys _do_ work, as I mentioned above in my edit/comments, but I might not be settings things up in a preferred way.Your solution looks like it would work. Would it error out if the values for `key` were duplicates?

Comment: In my solution you can have many or all the same keys but you could check that manually since static_key is an array.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did as here explained, but got an error `Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "path.route.exchange". Available options are "key", "value".` Any ideas what to check first?

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('static_key')
            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
            ->defaultValue([])
        ->end()
    ->end();
```