# Symfony configuration component : array prototype and useAttributeAsKey

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, components

I'm using [Config component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config.html) on a standalone PHP app, and I would like to have in my configuration file a structure similar to below :

```
sites:
  site1:
    ftp:
      server: myserver
      name: name
      ...: ...
    database:
      server: myserver
      name: ....
```

AFAIS, I need the useAttributeAsKey() method on my array for the "site1" node ("sites" node can handle several sites, with name as key).

I tried to set it up this way, but I end up to a "children method not in NodeDefinition". How to set it correctly?

```
$rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode(self::REMANENCE_NODE[self::NODE_NAME])
                    ->defaultValue(self::REMANENCE_NODE[self::NODE_DEFAULT_VALUE])
                    ->info('Contains the backup folders max value to keep on defined storages')
                ->end()
                ->arrayNode(self::SITES)
                    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                    ->prototype('array')             
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode(self::DATABASE)
                        ->end()
                        ->arrayNode(self::FILES)
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
```

Thanks for your replies,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the good configuration :

```
$rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode(self::REMANENCE_NODE[self::NODE_NAME])
                ->defaultValue(self::REMANENCE_NODE[self::NODE_DEFAULT_VALUE])
                ->info('Contains the backup folders max value to keep on defined storages')
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode(self::SITES)
                ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode(self::DATABASE)
                            ->children()
                                ->scalarNode(self::DATABASE_SERVER[self::NODE_NAME])
                                    ->defaultValue(self::DATABASE_SERVER[self::NODE_DEFAULT_VALUE])
                                    ->info('Contains the database server IP or name')
                                ->end()
```

This above works for following configuration :

```
configuration:
  remanence: 5
  sites:
    site_1: # this is the attribute as key
      database:
        server: localhost
        ... : ...
```

2 things to notice :

- prototype('array') seems to handle key as attribute in this case.
- I use PHPStorm which provides informations using PHPDoc and I currently have a underlighted children() method (after prototype one) indicating me warning I mentionned in original question. I will dig deeper later, but it seems to have a mess in here.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288144/how-to-define-dynamic-configuration-using-the-treebuilder) showed me the right way, which is also what suggest [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-node-options)

Cheers,

Nicolas