# Symfony 4: how to allow dynamic values for array nodes in bundle configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In the `Configuration` of my bundle I have defined the following for example:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('foo');
$treeBuilder
    ->getRootNode()
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('foobar')
            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
            ->defaultValue([])
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

i. e., the bundle expects an array of values in `foo.foobar`. Now, in the case of my bundle, these values are dependent on the environment the application is run in. Thus it would make sense to provide this configuration value through an environment variable. [Since Symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables) values of environment variables can be processed. So this array could be stored JSON encoded in the environment variable and then be decoded via `%env(json:FOO)%`. So instead of having to write

```
foo:
    foobar:
        - Lorem
        - Ipsum
        - Dolor
```

one could instead use

```
foo:
    foobar: '%env(json:FOO)%'
```

where

```
FOO=["Lorem","Ipsum","Dolor"]
```

However, when trying to do that Symfony throws the following exception:

```
A dynamic value is not compatible with a "Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\PrototypedArrayNode" node type at path "foo.foobar".
```

What is the correct way of allowing such dynamic values for array nodes? Do I need to implement my own normalization in the configuration tree for example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288144/how-to-define-dynamic-configuration-using-the-treebuilder looks similar from what you're trying to achieve ... (question has a different spin, so does the answer, but the answer looks very different from your code)

Comment: Hm, no that does not help and is not similar at all. My problem specifically has to do with the environment variable processors and allowing such dynamic values in the configuration tree - e.g. for a scalar array node.

Comment: Try `%env(string[]:json:FOO)%`

Comment: @EugeneRuban that does not work either: `Invalid "env(string[]:json:FOO)" name: only "word" characters are allowed.`

Comment: Hm, check this issue for references https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28137

Comment: @EugeneRuban I posted there too: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28137#issuecomment-640038485 ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work if you plugin a regular string env value?  And you sure this is even supposed to work?  Most ENV examples I have seen involve setting parameters.  And since the value has to be read fresh on each request, they end up calling a special function when injecting the value.  Since the final product of processConfiguration is just an array, I don't really see how they can do that.  But could be wrong.

Comment: @Cerad since posting the question I have read up more on the discussion on this on GitHub. And yes, it seems to be deliberate for exactly that reason: performance and validation. The values need to be known at compile time currently rather than run time. However accepting that there may be a performance penalty, I thought there must still be a way to make this work. Otherwise why have the `json:` processor in the first place? For my purposes using environment vars for this configuration is not hugely important - and may be it does not make sense in the end anyway. But I still wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between static yaml config and `'%env(json:FOO)%'`: content of env variable is not available at compile time. See [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables):

> You can reference environment variables using the special syntax %env(ENV_VAR_NAME)%. The values of these options are resolved at runtime (only once per request, to not impact performance).

In your `BundleExtension` (at compile time) your config value `foobar` will contain string like `env_514deb50f3dcab34_json_FOO_ac251f2b9ef3c85f94a68df880763311` (instead of real array).

That means you can't conditionally load some configuration in your bundle, for example.
However, this node should be validated at compile time. In case of JSON it cannot be validated as `scalarNode(...)`, because contain JSON env-processor. It cannot be validated as `arrayNode(...)`, because `ArrayNode` does not support dynamic values.
So you may skip the validation:

```
$treeBuilder
    ->getRootNode()
    ->children()
        ->variableNode('foobar')->end()
    ->end()
;
```

You may also add two different config items in bundle: for static configuration (as arrayNode) and for dynamic configuration (as variableNode) and then check in the extensions that only one of them is defined.

PS: It looks inconvenient. But these are quite natural limitations, if we remember that environment variables can be changed in runtime (i.e. after compiling the container).

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the JSON in the .env file as **string**

this is correct: `FOO='["Lorem","Ipsum","Dolor"]'`